# Unable to scrape Google

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, guzzle, goutte

I'm trying to scrape google for [reverse image search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378354/reverse-image-scraping-with-php) results using [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) (its basically a wrapper around Guzzle + Symfony DOM parser).

I'm doing:

```
$googleURL = "https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=".$imageURL;

$crawler = $client->request('GET', $googleURL);
$client->followRedirects(true);
print_r($crawler,1);
```

.. and the output (https://paste.ee/p/spfYA) contains the correct URL but the `body` (HTML) is of the default search page, the one without results.

What should I do to get the search results as HTML.

Comment: After a few requests, Google will get your IP banned. So you might need to use their API-s instead

Comment: Thats alright, I need to get only a few hundred in a span of few days. Besides, there's no API for reverse image search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All I had to do was set the user-agent:

```
$client->setHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36');
```